# When the screen orientation changes the system will, by default, destroy the current activity and create a new one while preserving its state

Tags: android

I can not able to understand this sentence in android documention. Since it is saying

> When the screen orientation changes the system will, by default, **destroy the current activity.**

and it also saying

> create a new one while **preserving its state.**

but actully it is contrary. How could it be? Can anybody explan to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this [Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)
And [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android) where it discussed in detail